# How to send numpy array or float values in AWS API response?

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, api, response

How to receive a numpy ndarray in AWS REST API response ? Does API response supports any other format than JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use JSON and you would serialize your  `ndarray` into a string. Then on the client side you would convert the string to `ndarray` back.